how to change the existing "add to model" url in django admin
enter image description here
So like this, I created a proxy model then I registered the proxy model, now I want to create a proxy for this model, when I go to the form, it will be added to the model that the proxy model was created for.
model.py
class Congregation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    masteruser = models.OneToOneField(
        Master,
        verbose_name='Master Data',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='Congregation',
    )
    member_number = models.IntegerField()
    alias_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    chinese_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_congregation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    worship_id = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Data Jemaat'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Data Jemaat'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.masteruser.full_name

model_proxy.py
from master.models import Congregation,

class CongregationManage(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CongregationManage, self).get_queryset().filter( is_congregation=True )
class CongregationProxy(Congregation):
    objects = CongregationManage()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

admin.py
class CongregationProxyAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('full_name' ,'alias_name', 'chinese_name', 'member_number', 'address' )
    date_hierarchy = 'created_at'

    def full_name(self, obj):
        return obj.masteruser.full_name
    def address(self, obj):
        return obj.masteruser.address
    
admin.site.register(CongregationProxy, CongregationProxyAdmin)

So what I hope is that when the congregationProxyAdmin clicks the add button, the URL will be the first one http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/master/congregationproxy/add/ become http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/master/master/add/#group-fs-Congregation--inline-Congregation
